# Requirements that base on alrady existing requirements

Tags: specifications, requirements

Let's assume that there is a working system with planty of functions and the system is now going to be adjust for another country. Some functions stay as they are, some are going to be adjust and some are going to be define from scratch.

In which form would you write requirements in this situation? Should the new specification mentione about already existing functions? Should every function be described new? If there is a big use case which needs a small change for the new country should it be describe complet or just the diff? What about the context for such small change so that developers understand what it is about?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

> In which form would you write requirements in this situation?

In the same as before, if you are happy with it.

> Should the new specification mentione about already existing functions?

It really should. That will help developers and reduce the risk of redundant logic being developed.

> Should every function be described new?

Creating so much duplicate content will in most cases be against economic reason.
It will give you little to no added value but take a lot of precious time and money. Reusing requirements helps to do better.

Also, if you specify on top of existing requirements, you'll get a pretty good idea of what you can use from the existing, where to configure stuff and where to add something new (see your 2nd sentence).

Yes, you'll base your requirements on what you have specified already.

Exceptions to this rule may be (a) that specifying the new requirements as a diff is more effort than starting from scratch. Then you might ask whether the new stuff is really based on the existing or not.

Or, (b) you may find the already documented requirements to be of very poor quality in retrospect. Then it can help to give it a new approach.

> If there is a big use case which needs a small change for the new country should it be describe complet or just the diff?

You can fit it in the existing diagram if you've got the space. Or you can create sub diagrams and link to them for the details. The goal should be to keep the diagrams lean and understandable.
Generalization and `extend` / `include` are your friends.